# how to start work in LAMP server in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: lamp, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed ubuntu 10.04 recently and installed LAMP server following some tutorials, when i type localhost in firefox it shows Apache is working. problem is i don't know how to set up a php project in LAMP, basically i don't know how to start work using LAMP. i have experience with wamp where it has a www folder for working, how should i get started here.
please give me some instructions, and guidelines if possible tutorial links for this!

your help will be very valuble to me, because i'm planning to move to Ubuntu from windows,it's bit hard !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file in `/var/www called index.php` and put the following code in it.

```
 <?php 
 Print "Hello, World!";
 ?>
```

Comment: is there any way to move a directory in side this www directory? i mean when we are doing projects using codeigniter kind of frameworks we have to move our framework directory to this folder in order to develop, so how we can do that?  i have used "gksu nautilus" command, it allows me to move the directory inside to the folder, but when i create a project using eclipse it wont allow me to write to that folder? any way to make this folder writable? is there any permanent fix for this writing issue?

Comment: i found out the solution :) sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www  it worked :)